# editing a gif file in gimp stops the animation

Tags: border, edit, gif, gimp

I loaded a simple .gif file to GIMP, added a border to it and exported back to my folder as .gif file.
All I did was to add a border to the image in a new layer, shrinked the original layers and painting the gap between them.
Problem is, now i see the animation has stopped, when i open the .gif file it acts appears as a static image...

I'm sure its just a simple detail i'm missing here, it would help a lot if anyone could help out.

Thanks!

PS - Yes, i'm a GIMP newbie :(

Answer (score 3):

When you open an animated GIF in GIMP it makes each frame a layer. When you save it you need to tell GIMP these are not to be "squashed" into one layer (image), rather stored as an animated GIF

Did you do this?

BTW: A good tutorial http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Simple_Animations/